# Windows 7 compatibility with Apple Magic Mouse

Tags: windows-7, magic-mouse

Hey all. I'm planning to get an Apple Magic mouse and I'm wondering, does it work perfectly with Windows 7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. While you can use the Magic Mouse as a mouse (for left-click, right-click, and scrolling), multitouch features are not supported by Windows 7.

Comment: ...not natively, anyway.  (Presumably there is no driver for this because Apple is like that.)

Answer (score 0):

Officially the magic mouse isn't supported by windows 7. However, its fairly easy to get the multitouch working with windows 7. Just google how to make it work on a PC. You will need to download the bootcamp update from Apple and you will also need an extraction/compression program called 7-Zip.

Comment: "just google it" isn't a very helpful answer. Perhaps you could summarise the necessary steps here?